# PHP JavaScript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy generando desde un archivo PHP el contenido de una tabla para hacer modificaciones a los usuarios de un sistema. Tiene las funciones de activar y desactivar el usuario, pero cuando uso la función de cambiar el rol del mismo me lanza el error de "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Este es el código donde creo las funciones de JS:

```
$fnRol = "var conf = confirm(\"¿Está seguro de cambiar el rol del usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.\");
if (conf == true){
    var id = $(this).val() ;
    console.log($user_id);
    console.log($user_rol);
    var parametros = {
        \"user_id\" : ".$user_id.",
        \"user_rol\" : ".$user_rol."
    };
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   \"../update_desactivar.php\",
        type:  \"post\",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(\"#resultado\").html(\"Procesando, espere por favor...\");
        },
        success:  function (response) {
            alert(\"Usuario desactivado.\");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
};";


$fnDesactivar = "var conf = confirm(\"¿Está seguro de desactivar el usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.\");
if (conf == true){
    var id = $(this).val() ;
    console.log($user_id);
    var parametros = {
        \"user_id\" : ".$user_id."
    };
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   \"../update_desactivar.php\",
        type:  \"post\",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(\"#resultado\").html(\"Procesando, espere por favor...\");
        },
        success:  function (response) {
            alert(\"Usuario desactivado.\");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
};";


$fnActivar = "var conf = confirm(\"¿Quiere reactivar el usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.\");
if (conf == true){
    var id = $(this).val() ;
    console.log(id);
    var parametros = {
        \"user_id\" : id
    };
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   \"../update_activar.php\",
        type:  \"post\",
        beforeSend: function () {
                $(\"#resultado\").html(\"Procesando, espere por favor...\");
        },
        success:  function (response) {
                alert(\"Usuario activado.\");
                location.reload();
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
};";
```

Y este es el codigo donde genero los botones (aun estoy haciendo pruebas):

```
switch($row["estado"]){
    case TRUE : $estado = "Activo";
        $acciones=  "<div class='margin'>
                        <div class='btn-group'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fa fa-th-list'></i></button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                                <span class='caret'></span>
                                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span>
                            </button>
                            <div class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' x-placement='bottom-start' style='position: absolute; transform: translate3d(67px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;'>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnEntregado' value='$user_id' onclick='$fnDesactivar'>Desactivar usuario&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-close'></i></button>
                                <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
                                <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Cambiar rol:</a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <div class='btn-group-vertical'>
                                    <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'>
                                        Administrador&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                                <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'>
                                        Capturista&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                            <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'>
                                         Solo consulta&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
        break;

    case FALSE : $estado = "Desactivado";
        $acciones=  "<div class='margin'>
                        <div class='btn-group'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fa fa-th-list'></i></button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                                <span class='caret'></span>
                                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span>
                            </button>
                            <div class='dropdown-menu' role='menu' x-placement='bottom-start' style='position: absolute; transform: translate3d(67px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;'>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btnEntregado' value='$user_id' onclick='$fnActivar'>Reactivar usuario&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>
                                <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
                                <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Cambiar rol:</a>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <div class='btn-group-vertical'>
                                    <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnEntregado'>
                                        Administrador&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                                <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnEntregado'>
                                        Capturista&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                            <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnEntregado'>
                                         Solo consulta&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
}
```

El problema viene cuando al hacer click a uno de los botones que tiene el evento de la variable $fnRol es que me lanza el error y al momento de revisar donde esta el error la consola me da esto:

```
var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro de cambiar el rol del usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.");
                if (conf == true){
                var id = $(this).val() ;
                console.log(15);
                console.log(capt);
                var parametros = {
                    "user_id" : 15,
                    "user_rol" : capt
                };
                $.ajax({
                    data:  parametros,
                    url:   "../update_desactivar.php",
                    type:  "post",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                    },
                    success:  function (response) {
                            alert("Usuario desactivado.");
                            location.reload();
                    }
                });
                    }
                else{
                    return false;
                };(
```

La verdad no se de donde sale el ultimo parentesis, pero sin importar que contenido tenga esa variable siempre pone ese parentesis. El codigo completo esta en este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nx58fme7/).

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Tu problema parece radicar en esto `onclick='$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'`, no estas escapando las comillas, un ejemplo `onclick='$fnRol(\'$user_id\', \'$user_rol\')'`

Comment: Ahora imprime esto: ` else{      return false;  };(\ ` . Pero al menos me doy una idea de donde esta el error

Comment: Esto es php? `$fnRol = "var conf = confirm(\"` Si lo es debes empezar la frase con comillas simples, porque están todas las lineas abiertas. Le estás haciendo un lío a PHP y por eso te tira el error, has montado una string y la has cerrado donde te indico sin poner un punto y coma.

Comment: Lo mismo yo no me estoy enterando de algo, pero, ¿como le pasas parametros a una variale como `$fnRol`?. Por cierto, yo ejecuto el PHP independientemente y me devuelve el JS correctamente con las comillas como te las puse.

Comment: Las paso en el evento onclick de un boton. Vendria siendo este:

`<button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnRol' value='$folio' onclick='$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'> Solo consulta&nbsp;&nbsp;</br></button>`

Comment: Igual yo si mando a imprimir la variable con la funcion me la regresa de manera correcta. El problema se presenta cuando hago click en algun boton que use esa funcion, ahi es donde la consola del navegador me regresa el error.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde puedo entender con tu código, estás metiendo texto y JS en variables PHP. Siendo esto así, donde tienes el código JS has cometido un error:

A continuación a la variable `$fnRol` le pasas un string que empieza en "var y termina en confirm\" aunque le hayas intentado escapar las comillas en el string.

Para evitar estos problemas te recomiendo que uses siempre comillas simples con PHP y los strings que tengas pensado meter (yo estoy metiendo html en variables de PHP y es un dolor de muelas esto, pero siempre falla por lo mismo.

Te pongo el código corregido abajo y me dices si tira:

```
 $fnRol = 'var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro de cambiar el rol del usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.");
    if (conf == true){
        var id = $(this).val() ;
        console.log($user_id);
        console.log($user_rol);
        var parametros = {
            "user_id" : ".$user_id.",
            "user_rol" : ".$user_rol."
        };
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   "../update_desactivar.php",
            type:  "post",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                alert("Usuario desactivado.");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    };';


    $fnDesactivar = 'var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro de desactivar el usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.");
    if (conf == true){
        var id = $(this).val() ;
        console.log($user_id);
        var parametros = {
            "user_id" : ".$user_id."
        };
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   "../update_desactivar.php",
            type:  "post",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                alert("Usuario desactivado.");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    };';


    $fnActivar = 'var conf = confirm("¿Quiere reactivar el usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.");
    if (conf == true){
        var id = $(this).val() ;
        console.log(id);
        var parametros = {
            "user_id" : id
        };
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   "../update_activar.php",
            type:  "post",
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) {
                    alert("Usuario activado.");
                    location.reload();
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    };';
```

Por otro lado, al hacer la llamada a estas variables, lo haces desde un onclick pintado en una string que está entre comillas dobles. Esto hace que el JavaScript termine con los parentesis pintados: `$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'` y se confunda, por eso te dice que no está cerrado, porque pinta el `(` al finalizar el `return false;};'`.

No puedes pasar parametros a una variable, si a una función. Esto es debido a que has planteado mal el código del PHP y el HTML.

Tienes varias opciones. En lugar de pasar una variable `$fnRol` pásalo a una `function fnRol($user_id, $user_rol)` y en el onclick pones:

```
onclick="'.fnRol($user_id, $user_rol).'"
```

Igual para las otras 2 variables.

Un ejemplo:

```
function fnRol($user_id,$user_rol){
$js = 'var conf = confirm("¿Está seguro de cambiar el rol del usuario? Haga click en Aceptar para continuar.");
        if (conf == true){
            var id = $(this).val() ;
            console.log($user_id);
            console.log($user_rol);
            var parametros = {
                "user_id" : ".$user_id.",
                "user_rol" : ".$user_rol."
            };
            $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   "../update_desactivar.php",
                type:  "post",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    alert("Usuario desactivado.");
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }else{
            return false;
        };';
return $js;
}
```

Comment: Sigue saliendo el mismo error. Lo mas raro es que sea exactamente en la función de la variable $fnRol

Comment: Si, después de algunas pruebas veo que no es problema de PHP si no de JS. Estoy revisando y actualizo la pregunta con lo que sea.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Al parecer el error esta en el evento onclick de los botones, ya que cuando borro la parte donde estan los parentesis el error se quita.

Comment: Eso estoy viendo. Mi código no muestra los parentesis que te salen a ti, lo cual me parece raro. De donde salen las variables que pasas como parametro a los botones? `$user_id', '$user_rol` que contienen?

Comment: Les doy los valores que tienen como nombre ya que como mencione este PHP genera el contenido de una tabla haciendo una consulta en MYSQL. Las variables llevan esto:

`$user_id = $row["id"];
$user_rol = $row["rol"];`

Comment: Creo que el problema aparece porque en el onClick del boton estoy imprimiendo directamente el codigo en lugar de decirle que active una funcion. Entonces como la variable que esta en el onClick tiene el codigo y despues quiero mandar las 2 variables con los valores ahi es donde imprime enseguida el parentesis.

Comment: Me da la sensación que te está cogiendo el paréntesis de `$fnRol('$user_id', '$user_rol')'`. Esto es debido a que tu sistema de trabajo está mal planteado. Si quieres hacer un onclick no pases variables con variables como parametros. Manda una función como se suele hacer. Ponerle parentesis a una variable dentro de comillas dobles solo pinta el parentesis, y está confundiendo al JS, que ve un parentesis sin cerrar.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que pense, y si es eso. Ahora mi problema es que no se como pasarlos.

Comment: Si no te sirve esto vamos al chat. He actualizado la respuesta con una sugerencia de modificación a tu código. Me dices que tal. Un saludo.

Comment: De hecho ya estuve moviendo un poco y me di cuenta que la funcion si lleva las variables que necesita sin necesidad de pasarlas en el parentesis, asi que se los quite. Ahora el detalle esta en que la funcion  da error en la variable de rol porque no esta en parentesis o comillas simples.

Comment: Creo que seria mejor verlo en el chat, ya avance en la correcion pero aun tengo problemas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92772/discussion-between-jose-manuel-morales-and-carlos-roberto-luna-ochoa).